# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" when no response data is expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

I want to post the contents of a form using ajax to an URL in a different domain. I **don't** have control over the remote site response headers.

I can issue the POST request and the data goes through but get an error (using Chrome here):

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
```

I don't expect to get any data from the remote site, except for a *200* status code.

When using jQuery, if I set the dataType to *'jsonp'*, I get the 200 OK status code but I also get a warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

How can I still post the data to the remote server and simply ignore whatever response I might get (or not) with the exception of the status codes (200, 404, etc...)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just ignore the error.

Comment: Maybe use raw XMLHttpRequest, not jQuery